# Linear section of an algebraic variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

Let $\pi$ be a linear subspace of $\mathbb{P}^n$ and $X$ a reduced, irreducible variety of $\mathbb{P}^n$. Suppose that $\pi \cap X$ is reducible, hence $\pi \cap X=Y_1\cup Y_2 \cup \cdots Y_k$. When the degree of $Y_i$ is "small", i.e., when  $d < \dim \pi - \dim Y_i +1$, then we have that $\langle Y_i \rangle \subsetneq \pi$. My question is: can we have $\langle Y_i \rangle \subsetneq \pi$ if  $d \geq \dim \pi - \dim Y_i +1$?

Comment: What about a line, $\pi$  contained in a hypersurface ?  Doesn't $Y_1  = \pi $  work ?

Comment: Oops- didn't see the last condition that $Y \neq \pi $.

Comment: Okay, but what about a smooth cubic surface X in $\mathbb{P}^3$ .  Let $Y_1 \subset X $ be a line on X and $\pi$ a plane containing $Y_1$.  Then $ \pi \cap X = Y_1 \cup Y_2$ with $deg(Y_2) = 2$ If I understand your notation, then $d=2$ and $k=2$ and $dim(\pi) - dim(Y_2) +1 = 1$.